# Is there a type in TypeScript for anything except functions?

Tags: typescript

I would like to express that a paremeter should be an object or a simple value type (number, bool, string, etc.), but not a function.

If I use `Object`, the compiler let's me to assign a function.

```
var test: Object = () => "a";
```

If I use `any`, the same result of course too. Is there a type or trick which can help me out in this case?

My underlying goal is to garantee safety when using Knockout observables, so that I don't forget those little paranthesis to unwrap them :)

Comment: Interesting question. Might it be possible to flip this, instead of blacklisting not-allowed types, to whitelisting allowed types - ie: a typescript interface could to that. But I see your intent and I think an interface would fall a bit short there.

Comment: http://www.johnpapa.net/typescriptpost3/ ?

Comment: @JakeHeidt yes you're right, I need a general "all but functions" behaviour, which is hardly describable by interfaces.

Comment: Trying to restrict a parameter to one of a few selected types seems to be a surprisingly difficult thing to do even in many modern programming languages...  There really should be something akin to C's union type, but not quite there as with a union you still need to access different types via different properties.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## New Feature Answer

Added November 2018 - as conditional types are a thing now!

Conditional types provide a possible solution to this, as you can create a `NotFunction` conditional type, as shown below:

```
type NotFunction<T> = T extends Function ? never : T;
```

This works as follows:

```
const aFunction = (input: string) => input;
const anObject = { data: 'some data' };
const aString = 'data';

// Error function is not a never
const x: NotFunction<typeof aFunction> = aFunction;

// OK
const y: NotFunction<typeof anObject> = anObject;
const z: NotFunction<typeof aString> = aString;
```

The only weakness in this is that you have to put the variable on the left side and right side of the statement - although there is safety if you make a mistake such as:

```
// Error - function is not a string
const x: NotFunction<typeof aString> = aFunction;
```

## Original Answer

You can provide a runtime check using `typeof`, which although isn't a compile time check will catch those instances where you forget to execute the function:

```
function example(input: any) {
    if (typeof input === 'function') {
        alert('You passed a function!');
    }
}

function someFunction() {
    return 1;
}

// Okay
example({ name: 'Zoltán' });
example(1);
example('a string');
example(someFunction());

// Not okay
example(function () {});
example(someFunction);
```

## Why can't you actually do what you want?

You almost can, because you could use an overload to allow "one of many types", for example:

```
class Example {
    someMethod(input: number);
    someMethod(input: string);
    someMethod(input: boolean);
    someMethod(input: any) {

    }
}
```

Here comes the rub: in order to allow object types, you would have to add an overload signature of `someMethod(input: Object);` or `someMethod(input: {});`. As soon as you do this, functions would become allowed, because function inherits from object.

If you could narrow down `object` to something less general, you could simply add more and more overloads (yikes) for all the types you want to allow.

Comment: I know about this way, but as you wrote it's not a compile-time check. I already have checks like this, but the issue with it is that the whole application needs to be tested to get the errors. (I don't have an automated testing set up yet, and do not have the resources to build one currently.) I'll wait a few days in hope of someone having a better solution, and if not, I'll accept this answer as not having other possibilities.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I have added an explanation about why you can't do exactly what you want.

Comment: yes the main problem is that functions are objects themselves. I've accepted your answer because it really seems to be impossible to reach. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me solve similar problems 【NotArray】

Answer (score 17):

You can do this in TypeScript 2.8 with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316).

```
type NotFunc<T> = Exclude<T, Function>
function noFunc <T> (notF: T & NotFunc<T>) { return notF }

const f = () => 2

noFunc(f) // error!
noFunc(f()) // compiles!
```

If the type system can decide that `T` extends `Function` (i.e., `T` is a function) then the type will be `never`, which is a compile-time error. Otherwise, the type will be `T` and your code will compile.

However, you should read this to more clearly understand what is happening:

```
// type NotFunc<T> = T extends Function ? never : T
type NotFunc<T> = Exclude<T, Function>

// the imporant cases for us are any and {}
type AnyNotFunc = NotFunc<any> // any
type ObjNotFunc = NotFunc<{}> // {}
type NullNotFunc = NotFunc<null> // never

// some functions, explicitly typed and inferred
const f: Function = () => 2
const ff = () => 2
const g: Function = (): null => null
const gg = (): null => null

// so a function like this won't work:
function badNoFunc <T> (notF: NotFunc<T>) { return notF }

// these all compile, because T is inferred as {} and NotFunc<{}> is just {}
badNoFunc(f)
badNoFunc(g)
badNoFunc(ff)
badNoFunc(gg)

// so need the T & NotFunc<T> to give the compiler a hint as to the type of T
function noFunc <T> (notF: T & NotFunc<T>) { return notF }

// now f is correctly inferred to be Function
noFunc(f) // error! f is assignable to Function
noFunc(g) // error! g is assignable to Function
noFunc(f()) // OK! 2 is not assignable to Function

// but we would expect g() === null to be never since NotFunc<null> === never
noFunc(g()) // OK? even though null is assignable to Function?
noFunc<null>(g()) // Error! Ah, type Function represents () => any but NotFunc<null> is never

// if we use the implicitly typed version, gg, the compiler infers the null return value correctly
noFunc(gg()) // Error! Correct

noFunc(ff) // error! The type is correctly inferred to be function
noFunc(gg) // error! The type is correctly inferred to be function
noFunc(ff()) // OK! 2 is not assignable to Function
```

Takeaways:

1. The OP can do what they want
2. The `Function` type is as bad as `any`, so avoid it

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach that defines all valid (non-function) values and then uses a recursive definition. I think this works for my case and hopefully for anyone else who comes across this question.

[Example on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NoFunctionValue%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20NoFunctionObject%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20NoFunctionArray%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20NoFunctionObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20NoFunctionValue%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20NoFunctionArray%20extends%20Array%3CNoFunctionValue%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Try%20putting%20a%20function%20anywhere%20in%20here%20to%20see%20error%0D%0Aconst%20text%3A%20NoFunctionObject%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bool%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20str%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20num%3A%207%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nul%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20undef%3A%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arr%3A%20%5Btrue%2C%20'string'%2C%207%2C%20null%2C%20undefined%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bool%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20str%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%3A%207%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nul%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20undef%3A%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr%3A%20%5Btrue%2C%20'string'%2C%207%2C%20null%2C%20undefined%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20)

```
type NoFunctionValue =
    boolean
    | string
    | number
    | null
    | undefined
    | NoFunctionObject
    | NoFunctionArray

interface NoFunctionObject {
    [key: string]: NoFunctionValue
}

interface NoFunctionArray extends Array<NoFunctionValue> { }

// Try putting a function anywhere in here to see error
const text: NoFunctionObject = {
    bool: true,
    str: 'string',
    num: 7,
    nul: null,
    undef: undefined,
    arr: [true, 'string', 7, null, undefined],
    obj: {
        bool: true,
        str: 'string',
        num: 7,
        nul: null,
        undef: undefined,
        arr: [true, 'string', 7, null, undefined]
    }
}
```

Comment: This work, but the problem is, when You try to access text.obj.num or type.obj.bool, 
The compiler will complain.

Comment: Unfortunately, values that have interface types and do not have an index signature cannot be assigned to NoFunctionValue

Answer (score 1):

With typescript 1.8, you can get pretty close if you define function as something that has all 4 properties: caller, bind, apply and call:

```
interface NoCaller {
    caller?: void;
}
interface NoBind {
    bind?: void;
}
interface NoApply {
    apply?: void;
}
interface NoCall {
    call?: void;
}

type NotAFunction = NoCaller | NoBind | NoApply | NoCall; // if it fails all 4 checks it's a function


function check<T extends NotAFunction>(t: T) {
    // do something
}

function f() {
}

class T {
}

var o = new T();

check({});
check(o);
check({caller: 'ok', call: 3, apply: this});

//check(f); // fails
//check(T); // also fails: classes are functions, you can't really escape from javascript
```

Surprisingly, the error message is not that bad:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NoCaller | NoBind | NoApply | NoCall'.
  Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'NoCall'.
    Types of property 'call' are incompatible.
      Type '(thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface, which doesn't accept functions.
You can extend from this interface and it will prevent from having methods in inherited type.
In contrast from previous answers it:

- Blocks functions in nested objects
- With with optional (?) fields

---

```
export type Serializable<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Required<T>[K] extends Function ? never : T[K] & Serializable<T[K]>
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].