# Given the type "anything except function OR function", how do I check if it's a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements

Why is the `value` not of type `() => string` after the `if (typeof value === 'function')` check?

What check should be made, so that the type is inferred correctly (making the cast unnecessary)?

```
function foo<T extends {}>(value: Exclude<T, Function> | (() => string)) {
    let result: string;

    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        result = value(); // Error: Type '(() => string) | (Exclude<T, Function> & Function)' has no compatible call signatures.
        result = (value as () => string)(); // works, but I don't like it
    } else {
        result = value.toString();
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: @Fenton This is related to your helpful answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613955/is-there-a-type-in-typescript-for-anything-except-functions, so maybe you'd know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is typescript can't do a lot of reasoning about conditional types while there are still unresolved parameters in them (like `T` while inside the function). So when encountering a type-guard, typescript will just intersect the parameter type with `Function` resulting in `(() => string) | (Exclude<T, Function> & Function)` which is still not callable.

By far the easiest way to get around this is to use a type assertion.

You can also express the condition in a different way. A function must have a `call` method. If we constrain `T` to, if it has a `call` member, it be of a type incompatible with the `call` in function, we would be in effect excluding `T` from being function:

```
function foo<T extends number | string | boolean | null | undefined | ({ call?: undefined; [k: string]: any }) = never>(value: T | (() => string)) {
    let result: string;

    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        result = value(); // ok 
    } else {
        result = value.toString();
    }

    console.log(result);
}

foo(1)
foo({
    o: ""
})
foo(() => "");
foo(() => 1); // error
```

Perhaps the new [negated types features](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) will improve the capabilities of typescript to reason when type parameters are involved. While `Exclude` does a good job of filtering a type, it is not a 100% substitute for a negated type.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, somebody just created a github issue for this a couple of days ago: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29614