# Typescript type for user generated object

Tags: typescript

I recently stumbled upon one problem.

in typescript, if we create function that supposed to accept user generated object.
we use `any`.

```
  // will pass object to google-analytics
  function sendGoogleAnalytics(a: any){

     //should pass any user-generated object but not promise, Date, Array
     PostRequestToGA(a);
  }


  // Expected Example:
  sendGoogleAnalytics('asdf');
  sendGoogleAnalytics({hello: 'world'});
  sendGoogleAnalytics({anyKey: 'world', another: 'world2'});
 
  // but should prevent sending Promise, Date, or built-in javascript object. 
  // example below, should be prevented at compile time
  sendGoogleAnalytics(fetch('google.com'))
  sendGoogleAnalytics(()=>{})
  sendGoogleAnalytics(new Date())
```

But this is bug waiting to happen. 
for example, when I accidentally pass a Promise. It will break silently without compiler error.

if I restrict the type, I will need to create object for each type that I want to send.

But if I use `any` or `Object` it will allow `Promise`, `Function`, `Date`.

Do you have workaround for this? perhaps a generic type that avoid built-in javascript Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using conditional types; check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49262929/4800808